# How to create partial table that is linked to another controller on RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to link guests that are attending an event that has been created. They are in separate controllers but I want to show the guests details on the details of the event page.

I know that this a partial and can show it in a form but then it links back to the controller form when I want it to stay on the event page.

Created a partial form.

```
<div class="events show">
  <h2><%=@event.name%></h2>

  <table summary="Event view">
    <tr>

      <td><% if @event.cover_photo.attached? %>
        <image src="<%=(url_for(@event.cover_photo)) %>">
          <% end %>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th>Date of Event</th>
      <td><%= @event.date_of_event.strftime("%-d/%-m/%y %H:%M %Z") %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Description</th>
      <td><%= @event.description %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Location</th>
      <td><%= @event.location %></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <th>Response Cut-Off</th>
      <td><%= @event.rsvp_cut_off.strftime("%-d/%-m/%y %H:%M %Z") %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Created</th>
      <td><%= @event.created_at.strftime("%-d/%-m/%y %H:%M %Z") %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Updated</th>
      <td><%= @event.updated_at.strftime("%-d/%-m/%y %H:%M %Z") %></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
<div >
  <%= render @event.guestlists %>

  <h2>Add a guest:</h2>
  <%= render 'guestlists/form', guestlist: @event.guestlists.build %>
</div>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_event_path(@event) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', events_path %>
```

No errors, it shows the form to complete to create a guest but then takes the created guest and inputs it into the guestlist controller.

Comment: The above code is from my event index page which renders a form

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for the partial page generate the form content.

in the form_for doc;

```
form_for(record, options = {}, &block)

The rightmost argument to form_for is an optional hash of options:

:url - The URL the form is submitted to. It takes the same fields you pass to url_for or link_to. In particular you may pass here a named route directly as well. Defaults to the current action.

:namespace - A namespace for your form to ensure uniqueness of id attributes on form elements. The namespace attribute will be prefixed with underscore on the generated HTML id.

:html - Optional HTML attributes for the form tag.
```

So, as a solution, you should add a url params to partial.